# Can you prove that $f(x) > g(x)$ by proving that the Taylor series of $f(x)$ > Taylor series of $g(x)$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and I want to prove that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x > 0$. Given that it's pretty difficult to compute the difference analytically, I wanted to instead use the Taylor polynomials of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and argue that each individual term in the Taylor polynomial of $f(x)$ is greater than each term in the Taylor polynomial of $g(x)$ (in my case, this ends up actually being a lot more doable). I'm not sure this is mathematically sound so is there are argument for why this will or won't work? Thanks!

Comment: That works if you first prove that each Taylor series converges for all positive $x$.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: The easy way to see this (assuming convergence for all positive numbers) is to take the difference of the two series.  The term-by-term difference of two absolutely convergent series also absolutely converges, and under your hypotheses, it results in a series with positive terms, which must therefore be positive.  The Taylor series for the difference $f-g$ is therefore always positive when $x \gt 0$, so $f \gt g$.